# In Jeremiah 23:6 what does "the LORD Our Righteousness" mean?

Tags: hebrew, jeremiah, messiah

I noticed that the English translations of Jeremiah 23:6 vary greatly (http://biblehub.com/jeremiah/23-6.htm).

What is the proper rendering of the verse?

Is it about YHVH being righteous? Or making his people righteous? Or about his being bringing justice? Or about the messiah? Or about Josedech the high priest?

FYI, Brenton LXX has:

> Jer 23:6  In his days both Juda shall be saved, and Israel shall dwell
>   securely: **and this is his name, which the Lord shall call him,
>   Josedec among the prophets.**

Here is some information about Josedec:

http://bibleapps.com/j/josedech.htm

I notice that in Jeremiah 33:16 the same title is applied to Jerusalem:

http://biblehub.com/jeremiah/33-16.htm

Comment: If it helps, a gloss of the Hebrew in the Leningrad Codex (as it appears in BHS) would be: In-his-days will-be-saved Judah and-Israel will-dwell in-safety and-this [is] his-name which he-will-call-him Adonai our-righteousness. Those last three words are interesting in that depending on the syntax, it could be "his name which Adonai will call him: Our Righteousness" or "his name which (an implied subject "he") will call him: Adonai Is Our Righteousness" or even "his name which he will call Adonai: "our-righteousness".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Interesting, thanks. I am under the impression that Hebrew doesn't have a lot in the line of variants yet this one has YHVH: http://biblehub.com/interlinear/jeremiah/23-6.htm

Comment: (and to add to the above, I would probably opt for the second one based on the poetic structure balancing two halves of each sentence.) Yes, L has YHWH too - sorry, I just wrote "Adonai" out of habit from pronouncing it that way!

Comment: Can you please edit this to explain some of the great variety you see? While I see lots of small differences in the translations, I don't see anything of great substance, or anything that looks like more variety than you'd see for any random verse.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I tried to bring out more of the ambiguity of the verse. Let me know if it is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: @curiousdannii Any ms that includes "Josedec among the prophets" instead of "the LORD our righteousness" seems to be a significant variation! I'm also curious as to where that discrepancy appears regarding original texts. Is it LXX only?

Comment: @LukeSawczak  That does seem to be LXX only. I note it partially because it seems to take "he" to be a contemporary possibly messianic figure rather than a future one, the LORD or to Judah or Jerusalem as we see later in Jeremiah.

Comment: The original says merely, the Lord righteousness. There is no 'our'. The words are simply juxtaposed, 'The Lord' and 'righteousness'. They are equivalent. They express the same thing. There is no difference.

Comment: @NigelJ  Might it be the name https://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/josedech/

Comment: I understand the Masoretic text to read '_Jehovah tsidkenu_', which translates to 'The Lord righteousness'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jeremiah 23:5 Behold, the days come, saith the LORD, that I will raise unto David a righteous Branch, and a King shall reign and prosper, and shall execute judgment and justice in the earth.
>   
>  6 In his days Judah shall be saved, and Israel shall dwell safely: and this is his name which they shall call him, THE LORD OUR RIGHTEOUSNESS.

Both Jews and Christians agree that this is about the messiah.

Jer 23:6 says that many unspecified people will call the name of the Messiah, Jehovah our Righteousness. That means that they will know the Messiah as this, as the LORD who is our righteousness. When the indefinite pronoun is used as the subject to call the name of someone, it means that name is what the person really is. The Messiah really is Jehovah our Righteousness.

> Jeremiah 33:15 In those days, and at that time, will I cause the Branch of righteousness to grow up unto David; and he shall execute judgment and righteousness in the land.
>   
>  16 In those days shall Judah be saved, and Jerusalem shall dwell safely: and this is what they shall call her, The LORD [is] our righteousness.

Jer 33:15 talks about the messiah very similarly to 23:5.

v16 says that many unspecified people will call the holy city "Jehovah is our righteousness". That means that the holy city is a testimony of Jehovah becoming our righteousness through the Messiah in 23:6. In 33:16 the word "name" is not there as it is in 23:6. That is not what she is, but that is her testimony.﻿

Answer (score 1):

The Brenton Septuagint, and Jeremiah chapter 23:5 on wards...
Our creator says he will raise up to David a Righteous Branch, so it's not David spoken of...
This Righteous Branch, shall execute judgement and righteousness on the earth; we have yet to see such... 
In the days of this Righteous Branch, Juda shall be saved, and Israel shall dwell securely; this has not happened yet...
And this Righteous Branch is named as Josedec among the prophets; is talking of  Yehoshua, Yeshua, Joshua, or as the Greek and latin would have it, Jesus; with the name Josedec used to describe the office in relationship to God of the Righteous branch...
I have used my God given discernment, and everything required to understand the verses are given in the scripture provided, and in context of understandings of the authentic scriptures of our creator